# Переадресация поддомена, через .htaccess

Tags: mod_rewrite, html, php

mod_rewrite включен, прочитала очень много форумов, но не на одном нормально не объясняют.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.(com|ru)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*)\.domain\.(com|ru)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !games/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ games/%2/$1
```

Вот пример такого кода, я его прописываю в корне сайта, в .htaccess... Потом как пытаюсь зайти на games.domain.ru, выбивает ошибку 404, что я не так поняла?

Comment: Пробовала и этот способ:
http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/htaccess-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.67636/

Comment: А поддомен прописан в DNS ?

Comment: Rein, вот вот, а где у "radyx" его прописывать?  Я только сейчас докумекала, что не прописала в DNS...

Comment: А Вы домены через них покупали или у регистратора, вроде nik.ru ?

Comment: 2domains.ru ) а какую это роль играет?)

Comment: По крайней мере это обозначает, что запись в DNS есть в виде *****

Comment: ясно) так что мне делать?

Comment: Поменяйте местами 2 и 3 указания RewriteCond. Если не ошибусь, то это решит проблему.